# c# WIA 12 bit grayscale image loses quality as bitmap

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, wia

I am writing a windows forms application. I have an Image, received from CCD camera. The camera takes 12 bit grayscale **tiff** – 2 bytes per pixel. To receive it I am using WIA(windows image acquisition). I can make a byte array from the image data. After that I need to display the image in picturebox. When shown in picturebox, the image is too dark. Also, the created bitmap is Format32bppArgb. Do I lose quality, when creating the bitmap and how can I make the needed bitmap format? I am extremely new to image processing and any help will be great. I have read many forum posts on the topic of conversion between the formats, but with no luck so far.
So any ideas how to receive 16 bit grayscale bitmap from what I have so far?

Edit: This now is working:

```
    private void btnAdvancedTestSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       WIA.CommonDialog _dialog = new CommonDialogClass();
       WIA.Device _camera = _dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType, false, false);


        ImageFile imageFile = (ImageFile)_camera.Items[1].Transfer(EnvFormatID.wiaFormatTIFF);
        Byte[] receivedBytes = (byte[])imageFile.FileData.get_BinaryData();

        int bytecount = receivedBytes.Length;
        int width = imageFile.Width;
        int height = imageFile.Height;
        int dimension = width * height * 2;//number of bytes representing the image - 2 bytes per pixel
        int startImgBytes = bytecount - dimension;
        startImgBytes += 1;// from which position of the big array to start making pixel values
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[dimension]; //byte array with only bytes,representing the picture
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = startImgBytes; i < receivedBytes.Length; i++)//filling the only pixel byte data array
        {
            imageBytes[j] = receivedBytes[i];
            j++;
        }


         int pixDimension = width * height; //number of pixels in the image
         int[] pixVal = new int[pixDimension];
         int z = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < imageBytes.Length; i+=2)
         {
             int res = (imageBytes[i] * 0x100) + imageBytes[i + 1];//int value of the pixel, 2 bytes per pixel

             int pix = (res * 255) / 4095;// scalling down to 8 bit value
             pixVal[z] = pix;
             z++;
         }


         Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
         Color p;
         //grayscale
         int counter = 0;
         for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)//height
         {
             for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)//width
             {
                 int val = pixVal[counter];
                 newImage.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(255,val,val,val));
                 counter++;

             }
         }

         pbAdvanced.Image = newImage; //show the image in picture box
```

But this method is very slow for high resolution. Any ideas how to improve the speed. I read examples with Marshal.Copy and lockbits, but in all examples they use a source image and copy to new. Any help will be greately appreciated

Comment: TIFF is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  Actually being able to see a 12bpp grayscale's resolution is going to cost *thousands* of dollars on display hardware.  And not System.Drawing.  So just don't bother and use PNG instead, never any surprises.

Comment: Coming from the medical industry, if you want 12 bit grayscale use JPEG2000.  This is the standard format for DICOM